# OpenJPA @GeneratedValue internal behaviour

Tags: postgresql, openjpa

I have many entities in my core project with @GeneratedValue. As I read in the [documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/docs/openjpa-0.9.0-incubating/manual/manual.html#jpa_overview_mapping_sequence)

> uses a special single-row table to store a global sequence number

In my DB the table is already created:

```
CREATE TABLE openjpa_sequence_table
(
  id smallint NOT NULL,
  sequence_value bigint,
  CONSTRAINT openjpa_sequence_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And my question: does every insert in a table whose entity with the @GeneratedValue annotation increments the value of the sequence??

```
select * from openjpa_sequence_table
```

Retrieves exaclty the same value as `select (max) id from one_table`, which makes me think that the answer to my first question is NO.
But then, where do the other tables take the auto incremented id from?

The problem: we want to isolate OpenJPA and work only with store procedures in the DB. We realized the problem when we wanted to create a SP to insert different elements, how can I get the ID?? Currently all the IDs are generated in the openjpa_sequence_table.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

One of the entities using @GeneratedValue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email_address")
public class BlackListedAddress extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The auto-generated primary key.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private long id;
```

This table in the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE email_address
(
  email_id bigint NOT NULL,
  address character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT email_list_pkey PRIMARY KEY (email_id),
  CONSTRAINT email_list_unique_text UNIQUE (address)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: The provider usually generates blcks of IDs and caches them. This greatly improves concurrency. I really suggest using sequence generators instead though. Please show your entity mapping for a table + generator.

Comment: My question was edited. This model is in use since 2 years already, so change to sequence generators now doesn´t seem to be easy

Comment: Changing from table to sequence generation is quite trivial, generally. But "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" I guess.

Comment: And how could I initialized the sequences value? I don´t really know the current last ID generated by the openjpa sequence table

Comment: How does actually @GeneratedValue does?? where can I fin the implementation or de procedures in DB?

Comment: All in the OpenJPA source code. It is JPA provider specific. If you switched to sequences you would probably create per-table sequences and set their initial values as the max id +1 of the table the sequence is for. See existing SO answers for how to map sequences. Unless you have a performance problem perhaps it's best to leave it unchanged if you aren't used to DBA tasks and scripting.